# Download file through Google Chrome RemoteWebDriver- headless mode in Linux using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I am able to download files in headless chrome browser in windows machine using the below code:

```
ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, dc);

Map<String, Object> commandParams = new HashMap<>();
commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("behavior", "allow");
params.put("downloadPath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Downloads");
                            commandParams.put("params", params);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);

String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" +driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");

request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
httpClient.execute(request);
```

How can I use the same code with RemoteWebDriver in Linux where I am initializing the driver like this

> return new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("some url"), browserCapabilities);